# Hadoop namenode not recognizing datanodes in docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose

I'm new and learning to start a hadoop system using Docker but I have been stuck at one point for weeks and finally I have to ask here. I could launch the containers individually without any problems and the namenode always recognized the running namenodes. However, when I tried to set up a Docker-compose.yml file to launch all containers at once, I got into multiple problems, one of which is that the namenode never recognized the running datanodes. Do you have any suggestions to help me fix it?

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
   version: "3"

services:
  base:
    image: hpcnube-base-image
  hpcnube-namenode:
    image: hpcnube-namenode-image
    depends_on:
      - base
    hostname: hpcnube-namenode
    container_name: hpcnube-namenode
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
    ports:
      - "9870:9870" 
  hpcnube-resourcemanager:
    image: hpcnube-resourcemanager-image

    container_name: hpcnube-resourcemanager
    depends_on:
      - hpcnube-namenode
      - hpcnube-dnnm2
      - hpcnube-dnnm1
    hostname: hpcnube-resourcemanager
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"

  hpcnube-dnnm1:
    image:  hpcnube-dnnm-image
    container_name: hpcnube-dnnm1
    hostname: hpcnube-dnnm1
    depends_on:
      - base
      - hpcnube-namenode
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
    #command: "/opt/bd/start-daemons.sh"
  hpcnube-dnnm2:
    #build:  ./DataNode-NodeManager
    image: hpcnube-dnnm-image

    container_name: hpcnube-dnnm2
    hostname: hpcnube-dnnm2
    depends_on:
      - base
      - hpcnube-namenode
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
    #command: "/opt/bd/start-daemons.sh"
  hpcnube-checkpoint:
    image: hpcnube-checkpointnode-image
    hostname: hpcnube-checkpointnode
    depends_on:
      - base
      - hpcnube-namenode
      - hpcnube-resourcemanager
      - hpcnube-dnnm2
      - hpcnube-dnnm1
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
  hpcnube-timeline:
    image: hpcnube-timelineserver-image
    hostname: hpcnube-timelineserver
    depends_on:
      - base
      - hpcnube-namenode
      - hpcnube-resourcemanager
      - hpcnube-dnnm2
      - hpcnube-dnnm1
      - hpcnube-checkpoint
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net

  hpcnube-frontend:
    build: ./FrontEnd
    hostname: hpcnube-frontend
    depends_on:
      - base
      - hpcnube-namenode
      - hpcnube-resourcemanager
      - hpcnube-dnnm2
      - hpcnube-dnnm1
      - hpcnube-checkpoint
      - hpcnube-timeline
    hostname: hpcnube-frontend
    networks:
      - dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net
    ports:
      - "2345:22" 



networks:
  dockerfiles1_hpcnube-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: @Jan V., are your containers on different physical hosts? because if they do, you cannot use bridge network. In fact, bridge network is for several containers on one host.

Comment: @M_Gh No all my containers are on the same machine. I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Jan V., please take a look at this (https://ordina-jworks.github.io/docker/2018/09/24/docker-networking-with-weave.html). You can make a network via Weave easily.